# TinyMCE does not resize images in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, tinymce

So, I am using TinyMCE 3.5.9. Works great, except when an image is resized in IE. TinyMCE does not append a style tag to the width and height tags. This causes an issue in Internet Explorer 10,9,8 etc.. IE requires a style tag for width and height otherwise it is ignored.

How do you fix this? Has anyone else run into this? Below is my implementation of the plugin.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        editor_selector: "richText",
        plugins: "paste,table,advimage,advlink,media,directionality,fullscreen,preview",
        //valid_children: "+head[style],+body[style]",
        verify_html: false,
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "outdent,indent,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,|,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "tablecontrols,link,unlink,image,|,forecolor,backcolor,media,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "formatselect,fontselect,|,ltr,rtl,|,visualaid,fullscreen,preview",
        theme_advanced_disable: ",help,hr,removeformat,sub,sup,backcolorpicker,charmap,anchor,newdocument",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        remove_trailing_nbsp: true,
        entity_encoding: "numeric",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        language: "en",
        document_base_url: "",
        extended_valid_elements: "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]"
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Twitter Bootstrap css overrides the img tag and applies some style attributes to it. Commenting out this line fixed my issue.

```
img {
    width: auto\9;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    /*-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;*/ -- THIS LINE, COMMENT IT OUT.
}
```